# Unable to find checkbox with Capybara

Tags: selenium-webdriver, checkbox, capybara, visibility

Unable to find checkbox with Capybara.

This is the HTML:

```
<div class='check-group'>
 <div class='checkbox'>
   <input type="checkbox" name="accepts_fcra" id="accepts_fcra" value="1" />
   <label for="accepts_fcra"><span>Some text <a title="FCRA" target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com/fcra">FCRA</a> some text.</span></label>
 </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to check the checkbox with the id "accepts_fcra".

I've tried a bunch of stuff and all pretty much return the same thing: "Unable to find (method used to find checkbox)"

Some attempts:

```
check("#accepts_fcra")
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find checkbox "#accepts_fcra"

find("#accepts_fcra").set true
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find css "#accepts_fcra"

within("div.checkbox") do
  find(:xpath, "//input[@id='accepts_fcra']")
end
Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "//input[@id='accepts_fcra']"
```

But the 2 classes above the checkbox, ".check-group" and ".checkbox" are found, just the checkbox is not found. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured it out, tried this:

```
find("accepts_fcra", :visible => false).click
```

And it worked, the element was 'invisible', so just had to pass that in along with the find and click for it to work.

Comment: If this is for testing an app, interacting with an invisible element is not recommended.  Also, not all of Capybaras drivers will click on an invisible element so your tests become driver specific and are likely to break in the future when whichever driver you're using switches to not clicking on invisible elements.  Instead you should perform whatever actions a user would perform, maybe clicking on the label -  `find('label[for="accepts_fcra"]').click` for instance

Comment: @Tom, tried your method but it didn't work, it actually clicked a link within the text/label for the radio button.

But also the checkbox isn't actually invisible to the user, I can physically see it, so in this case I'd think it should be ok, your point I think makes more sense if the actual element was actually physically invisible.

Comment: If Capybara says it's not visible, I'm willing to bet what you're seeing on the screen isn't actually the checkbox - it's more likely to be images being used (via JS/CSS)  to style checkboxes the same across multiple browsers.   Since you're HTML above doesn't show a link in the label that was impossible to predict :)  You really should look at the html from the live page (after JS widgets have run) and figure out what actual element the user would be clicking on rather than having Capybara click invisible elements - your test as currently written  will stop working as drivers update

Comment: Hmmm...well from the HTML the only thing that makes sense to click on in regards to the checkbox is:    <input id="accepts_fcra" type="checkbox" value="1" name="accepts_fcra"></input>

Comment: Maybe add the complete section of HTML from the browser (not from your templates) to the question above

Comment: Updated the html with the relevant HTML from the page

Comment: Ok - so when trying to click on the label - it clicks in the middle of the labels bounding box - which in your case means the link.  Unfortunately nothing else in the label is individually findable (if "Some text" was in its own span for instance you could find and click that) which means there may be nothing you can do in a cross driver manner in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the help and feedback, really appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `visible: false` solution didn't work for me.

This was because the checkbox was hidden, like so

```
 input[type="checkbox"]{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    opacity:0;
}
```

and a funky checkmark style was being used instead.

However, clicking the label worked for me

eg./

`page.find(:xpath, "//label[@for='accepts_fcra']").click`